# Sticky navbar with React Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, navbar

I'm trying to setup a sticky navbar with nextjs but the resulting navbar is not working like it should. Can anyone help with the code below?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './navbar.module.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    const [scrolled, setScrolled] = React.useState(false);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const offset = window.scrollY;

        if (offset > 200) {
            setScrolled(true);
        }
        else {
            setScrolled(false);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    })


    return (
        <div className={scrolled ? styles.scrolled : styles.navbar}>
            <ul className={styles.ul}>
                Something
            </ul>
            Navbar
        </div>
    )

};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working like it should" ? Can you describe what exactly happens that you don't want, or does not happen that you want ?

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to have a sticky navbar, you can do it with pure CSS with `position: sticky` like this:

```css
header, nav, main {
  padding: 1.7rem 1rem;
}

header {
  background-color: #d99;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: #9d9;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #99d;
}
```

```html
<header>
Header
</header>
<nav>
  Navbar
</nav>
<main>
  Main
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would fix your problem, but you could try changing your `useEffect` to have an empty dependency array at the end of it so that it runs when the component mounts, like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
}, [])
```

Comment: I don't know if it fixes the problem, but at least it removes some memory leaks. You can also add a `window.removeEventListener` in the `return` like [here](https://react-hooks-cheatsheet.com/useeffect#effect-with-cleanup) to clean the listener on component unmount.

Comment: It kinda worked for a second but now whenever it switches to the second style the navbar blinks/glitches

Comment: I even tried using useLayoutEffect and I get the same flickering

Comment: Changed the position property  in the css file for the scrolled mode from fixed to sticky and now it works without the flickering.